# Lognormal of a time derivative

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Im trying to understand the following math passage from a article i'm reading: 
The main equation is:

$$\frac{dW_{ic}^{t}}{W_{ic}^{t}}= [R_{L}+(R_{O}-R_{L})D_{i}+b'\textbf{x}+a_{c}]dt + d\epsilon_{i}^{t}$$

Then, looking to the dynamic between time t=0 and time t=1, and assuming that:

$$d\epsilon_{i}^{t}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,dt)$$

Passing the log yelds:

$$log W_{ci}^{1}=log W_{ci}^{0}+(R_{O}-R_{L})D_{i}+b'\textbf{x}+\underbrace{R_{L}+a_{c}-\frac{1}{2}}_{\equiv \alpha}+\epsilon^{1}_{`i}$$

I do not understand completely how to arrive in this last equation from the first one. I think that the $-1/2$ is the variance correction from the lognormal, but i miss something. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $d \epsilon_i^t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, dt)$ is very strange to me but I believe I understand what they mean. Integrating both sides of the equation from $0$ to $1$:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dW_{ic}^{t}}{W_{ic}^{t}} = \log W^1_{ci} - \log W_{ci}^0 $$

$$\int_0^1[R_{L}+(R_{O}-R_{L})D_{i}+b'\textbf{x}+a_{c}]dt = [R_{L}+(R_{O}-R_{L})D_{i}+b'\textbf{x}+a_{c}]$$

$$ \int_0^1 d\epsilon_{i}^{t} = \epsilon_i^1 - 1/2$$
Where the half is coming from PDF of a normal centered around $0$, evaluated at $0$.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks!!!